# select options pushed out of bounds only when embedded in iframe, but only on external monitor

Tags: google-chrome, iframe

I have embedded a qualtrics survey into an iframe. When I view the survey in Chrome, the dropdown options are offset, as shown below:

[image]

Live demo [here](https://daveeargle.com/broken-qualtrics-chrome)

If I resize the window, the options properly realign. I am having trouble discerning which, if any, qualtrics css rule is causing this to happen.

It does *not* happen if I load the qualtrics link directly -- e.g., not embedded in an iframe. [direct link](https://cuboulder.qualtrics.com/jfe/form/SV_4MAOW4totCNg3rf)

Furthermore, if I load a non-qualtrics page with a dropdown, the select option is not affected.

What may be causing this?

Edit: I give up. Exclusively happens when Chrome is on my external monitor.

Edit 2: Related to [this Chrome bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=659642) related to external monitor rendering

Comment: Using Chrome and your live demo link above, I don't see the problem you describe. The drop down options look fine.

Comment: I did some further testing, and it seems to only happen when Chrome is displayed on the external monitor I'm using. In hindsight, some chrome extensions also get offset by probably the same amount when on that monitor. Haven't tried with various monitors but I'm back-burnering this for now.

Comment: @deargle, were you ever able to get this fixed? We're running into the same issue with an embedded iframe and haven't been able to find a solution.

Comment: @jg314 have you tried https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=659642#c71

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply @deargle. Disabling chrome://flags/#enable-use-zoom-for-dsf does fix it for me, but unfortunately, these select dropdowns are going to be used by our clients. We can't ask them all to disable that Chrome feature. Were you able to find any solution through code that works?

Comment: @jg314, negative. I think that the chrome bug report is the best place to push for a fix.

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot for the help @deargle. It's very much appreciated.